# How do you paste without format by default in Google Sheets?

Tags: text-formatting, google-sheets

In Google Sheets you can hit Ctrl+Shift+V to paste without the formatting, but, is there a way to change it so that you can use Ctrl+V? Either by changing the Keystroke or forcing the rows or columns to only ever display unformated text?

(I know you can change the formatting later in a column, but, I am looking to force it to never take the formatting  in the first place, with just Ctrl+V no [SHIFT])

Comment: The best possible method is, create Macro and assign the Hot key CTRL+V to it. But remember in Google sheet Ctrl+V  is already been assigned to Paste, please refer this link, http://www.keyxl.com/aaad5ec/76/Google-Spreadsheet-software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm

Answer (score 1):

The built-in keyboard shortcuts cannot be customized or overridden in Google Sheets. The easiest solution is to bite the bullet and press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (on a Mac, use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.)

You can also try [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-i-create-macros-bd0f29dc-5b89-3616-c3bf-ddeeb04da2fb) and [macOS](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac) features that let you press one key combination to send another key combination.

Comment: this answer does not work for me on firefox/windows

Comment: The answer refers to the **Edit > Paste special > Values only** command that only works when pasting from a range to another _within the same spreadsheet file_. To paste values only from one spreadsheet file to another, use the _web browser's_ **Paste and match style** command or similar.